# How to rotate, move or modify features using Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, drag-and-drop

I am looking for a Leaflet pluging for move (drag and drop), rotate or change a polygon or polyline feature. Also I´d like to capture the feature vertex coordinates once it has been moved to the new position. Otherwise is it posible to do that using perhaps OpenLayers o TurfJS? Which is the most appropiated way to do that, including saving modified feature into the backend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick search found this answer, so your question is possibly a duplicate question:

[Using Leaflet.Path.Transform to rotate polygons in Mapbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40555573/using-leaflet-path-transform-to-rotate-polygons-in-mapbox)

which leads to this leaflet plugin:

[Leaflet.Path.Transform](https://github.com/w8r/Leaflet.Path.Transform) which has [this beautiful demo page](https://milevski.co/Leaflet.Path.Transform/example/).

That looks like the answer to your question, minus the getting the feature coordinates, which might be solved by exploring the answers to this question: [Coordinates of Leaflet.Draw rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265835/coordinates-of-leaflet-draw-rectangle)

As for saving to the back-end, I would search something like 'leaflet draw save to [backend]'

Comment: I have been exploring some plugins but not the mentioned. I will check that

Comment: Demo URL has been updated: https://milevski.co/Leaflet.Path.Transform/example/

Comment: @danwild Thanks! Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe more of a long comment.. but:

The [Leaflet.draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) plugin covers most of the client-side functionality you're after - allowing users to draw/drag/edit etc.

But not rotate, which has been on an [open request](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/issues/120) since 2013.

As noted by @Barrat you can use [Leaflet.Path.Transform](https://github.com/w8r/Leaflet.Path.Transform) for rotation, however this won't play too nicely with Leaflet.draw (specifically, in terms of UX - they both provide their own interaction handlers which may conflict).

I've just started a plugin ([Leaflet.draw.rotate](https://github.com/onaci/Leaflet.draw.rotate)) to merge the functionality of these two together, however it does not yet support rotating polygons/polylines (it is on the roadmap though).